# HTML tag elements not interpreted by gmail when sending an email in PHP

Tags: php

Please help me out Good samaritans. I am trying to send an email with attachments from php code. The code works fine, it sends the email and all the attached documents.

But the problem with this code is that, the html tags are not interpred. They appear as they are. Below is the snapshot of the problem. 
[image: Email i recieve]

This is the code i use. Where am i getting it wrong. Where should i edit my code. Please help the guy out people. Thanx.

```
                            <?php

                                if(isset($_POST['sendmail']) && isset($_FILES['file']) )
                                {
                                    $message = '<html><body>';
                                    $message .= '<img src="http://jehucocloud.co.za/chamber/chamber/profile_img/fnb.png" alt="Website Change Request" />';
                                    $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
                                    $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" . $organisation . "</td></tr>";
                                    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . $organisationemail . "</td></tr>";
                                    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Subject:</strong> </td><td>" . $subject . "</td></tr>";
                                    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Our Website (main):</strong> </td><td><a href='". $organisationwebsite ."'>" . $organisationwebsite . "</a></td></tr>";
                                    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Message:</strong> </td><td>" . $text_message . "</td></tr>";
                                    $message .= "</table>";
                                    $message .= "</body></html>";

                                    $attachments = $_FILES['file'];

                                    if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
                                         foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $report_id){
                                            if($report_id != null)
                                            {
                                                $recipient_email .= ','.$report_id;
                                                $recipient_email[0] = '';
                                            }
                                        }
                                     }

                                    if($recipient_email != null)
                                    {
                                        $file_count = count($attachments['name']); //count total files attached
                                        $boundary = md5("sanwebe.com");

                                        if($file_count > 0){

                                                 //header
                                                $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
                                                $headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n"; 
                                                $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$recipient_email."" . "\r\n";
                                                $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 

                                                //message text
                                                $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
                                                $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
                                                $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
                                                $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message));


                                                 //attachments
                                                for ($x = 0; $x < $file_count; $x++){       
                                                    if(!empty($attachments['name'][$x])){

                                                        if($attachments['error'][$x]>0) //exit script and output error if we encounter any
                                                        {
                                                            $mymsg = array( 
                                                            1=>"The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini", 
                                                            2=>"The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form", 
                                                            3=>"The uploaded file was only partially uploaded", 
                                                            4=>"No file was uploaded", 
                                                            6=>"Missing a temporary folder" ); 
                                                            die($mymsg[$attachments['error'][$x]]); 
                                                        }

                                                        //get file info
                                                        $file_name = $attachments['name'][$x];
                                                        $file_size = $attachments['size'][$x];
                                                        $file_type = $attachments['type'][$x];

                                                        //read file 
                                                        $handle = fopen($attachments['tmp_name'][$x], "r");
                                                        $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
                                                        fclose($handle);
                                                        $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content)); //split into smaller chunks (RFC 2045)

                                                        $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
                                                        $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
                                                        $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
                                                        $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
                                                        $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n"; 
                                                        $body .= $encoded_content; 
                                                    }
                                                }

                                                $sentMail = @mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);

                                                if($sentMail) //output success or failure messages
                                                {       
                                                    ?>
                                                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                                                            <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
                                                            <strong>You send an Email to all the selected recipients!</strong>
                                                        </div>
                                                    <?php
                                                }else{
                                                    ?>
                                                        <div class="alert alert-error">
                                                            <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
                                                            <strong>Could not send mail!</strong>
                                                        </div>
                                                    <?php  
                                                }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        ?>
                                            <div class="alert alert-error">
                                                <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
                                                <strong>You haven't selected recipients! You have to select atleast one recipient.</strong>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php 
                                    }
                                }
                            ?>
                            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                        <label class="control-label" for="input01">Subject</label>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input required type="text" class="span8" name="subject" value="<?php echo $subject; ?>"  id="input01">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                        <label class="control-label">Attachmnet</label>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input class="input-file" required name="file[]" multiple type="file">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                        <label class="control-label">Message</label>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <textarea required class="span12" rows="10"  name="text_message" cols="10"><?php echo $text_message; ?></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                         <div class="span12">
                                            <div class="nonboxy-widget">
                                              <div class="widget-head">
                                                <h5 class="pull-left"><i class="black-icons list_images"></i> Select Companies</h5>
                                            </div>

                                              <table class="data-tbl-striped table table-striped table-bordered">
                                                <thead>
                                                  <tr>
                                                    <th class="center"> <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="" class="checkall-task">
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th> Logo </th>
                                                    <th> RegNo </th>
                                                    <th> Company </th>
                                                    <th class="center"> Type </th>
                                                    <th class="center"> Bank </th>
                                                    <th class="center"> Account Status </th>
                                                    <th class="center"> Action </th>
                                                  </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                <?php

                                                    $query = "SELECT u.status,c.username,c.reg_no,c.enterprise_name,c.enterprise_type,c.bank,c.logo,c.email FROM company_details c,users u WHERE c.username=u.username order by c.enterprise_name";
                                                    $subject_set = mysqli_query($connection,$query); 

                                                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($subject_set))
                                                    {
                                                        if($row['status'] == 1 && $row['email']!='')
                                                        {
                                                         echo '<tr>
                                                            <td class="center tr-task-check"><input name="check_list[]" type="checkbox" value="'.$row['email'].'"></td>
                                                            <td class="center"><span class="user-thumb"><img src="../../y/profiles/'.$row['logo'].'" width="100" height="100" alt="User"></span></td>
                                                            <td>'.$row['reg_no'].'</td>
                                                            <td>'.$row['enterprise_name'].'</td>
                                                            <td class="center">'.$row['enterprise_type'].'</td>
                                                            <td class="center">'.$row['bank'].'</td>
                                                            <td class="center"><span class="label label-success">Active</span></td>
                                                            <td><div class="btn-group pull-right">
                                                                <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle"><i class="icon-cog "></i><span class="caret"></span></button>
                                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                                  <li><a href="/chamber/view_business/?reg='.$row["reg_no"].'"><i class="icon-file"></i> View Details</a></li>
                                                                </ul>
                                                              </div></td>
                                                          </tr>';
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            echo '<tr>
                                                            <td class="center tr-task-check"><input name="check_list[]" type="checkbox" value="'.$row['email'].'"></td>
                                                            <td class="center"><span class="user-thumb"><img src="../../y/profiles/'.$row['logo'].'" width="40" height="40" alt="User"></span></td>
                                                            <td>'.$row['reg_no'].'</td>
                                                            <td>'.$row['enterprise_name'].'</td>
                                                            <td class="center">'.$row['enterprise_type'].'</td>
                                                            <td class="center">'.$row['bank'].'</td>
                                                            <td class="center"><span class="label label-important">Expired</span></td>
                                                            <td><div class="btn-group pull-right">
                                                                <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle"><i class="icon-cog "></i><span class="caret"></span></button>
                                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                                  <li><a href="/chamber/view_business/?reg='.$row["reg_no"].'"><i class="icon-file"></i> View Details</a></li>
                                                                </ul>
                                                              </div></td>
                                                          </tr>';
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                ?>
                                                </tbody>
                                              </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <button type="submit" name="sendmail" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-retweet icon-white"></i> Send</button>
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your email headers to support HTML.

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Name <someone@example.com>, Name2 <someone2@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Your Name <youremail@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: someone@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: someone@example.com' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Thank you sir. You made me to realize something i was not aware of. Now it is working. I only changed                                                                                $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";                                  to be $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";